# Is there a reason why Roslyn does not optimize multiple increments?

Tags: c#, assembly, x86-64, compiler-optimization, roslyn

I was trying to see how `Roslyn` optimizes the following snippet:

*code*

```cs
public int F(int n) {
    ++n;       
    ++n;       
    ++n;       
    ++n;       

    return n;
}
```

**asm**

```
C.F(Int32)
    L0000: inc edx
    L0002: inc edx
    L0004: inc edx
    L0006: inc edx
    L0008: mov eax, edx
    L000a: ret
```

## Question

why doesn't Roslyn optimize it like an ahead-of-time C compiler like MSVC?  **4 x `INC`** is slower (4 cycle latency vs. 1 even assuming mov-elimination, and 4 more uops than necessary for throughput; https://agner.org/optimize/).

`C` "equivalent" of it:

```c
int
f(void *dummy_this, int n) {
        ++n;        
        ++n;        
        ++n;        
        ++n;        

        return n;
}
```

**asm** from MSVC, or GCC with `__attribute__((ms_abi))` to use the same Windows x64 calling convention as the C# asm: https://godbolt.org/z/sK6h7KKcn

```
f:
        lea     eax, [rdx+4]
        ret
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230322/discussion-on-question-by-hrant-is-there-a-reason-why-roslyn-does-not-optimize-m).

Answer (score -5, accepted):

The compiler does optimize. `n` is a parameter though, so it can't be modified. The JIT compiler must modify a *copy* of the parameter's value.

If the value is assigned to a variable before incrementing, the Roslyn compiler will eliminate the increments. From [this Sharplab.io snippet](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoBBmABM3AYVwG9NcL89YAXXAMQApbcoBKU8y7gNwgCdcMALxQA3F24UA1NJhipFSVNnzFuZd1ULFmytvWY9FBAHYhEjNwC+3TNaA=), this C# code :

```
public int F(int i) {
    var n=i;
    ++n;       
    ++n;       
    ++n;       
    ++n;       

    return n;
}
```

Will be translated to

```
public int F(int i)
{
    return i + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1;
}
```

And eventually compiled to this assembly code:

```
C.F(Int32)
    L0000: lea eax, [edx+4]
    L0003: ret
```

Comment: "`n` is a parameter though, so it can't be modified" - but `n` is `Int32`, a value-type. It isn't being passed by-`ref` - and both parameters and locals in the CLR's abstract stack behave the same, so I don't see why you're saying "it can't be modified".

Comment: @Dai is right. "n is a parameter though, so it can't be modified" doesn't make sense and is also flatly invalidated by the OP's disassembly (the register containing the parameter is clearly incremented, just not very efficiently). Assigning it to another variable shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I think you are correct. That's why I called this version a "workaround". However it's good to know that there is at least some way of doing it.

Comment: @Hrant: as discussed in comments on the question (now unfortunately moved to chat), this answer doesn't explain it (so you should un-accept it).  That's not how C# or the Windows x64 calling convention works.  (If `int i` was taken by ref (which it isn't), its value wouldn't be passed/returned in EDX; it would be by a pointer.  So `inc edx` is purely private the the function, and worse than mov+add, or LEA.)

Comment: @PeterCordes you are absolutely correct, but I'd say that this answer is better than nothing. And I also don't understand why was it moved to chat when there was extremely valuable information to read.

Comment: @Hrant: There is a useful workaround here, but that's all.  It shouldn't be the *accepted* answer because it's extremely misleading (by claiming that there's a reason for the missed optimization, and even seems to be making incorrect claims about C# arg semantics.)  You could post your own answer with the workaround, but pointing out that there's no good reason for it, or to have expected this in the first place.  (Feel free to copy or quote any of what I wrote in comments, e.g. about calling conventions.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I think it'll be a bit unfair, because you gave us the insight and proved us that it is in fact a weakness of JIT compiler. So yeah you can write the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't feel like a minimal answer repeating the fairly well-known fact that JIT compilers generally aren't as good as ahead-of-time, because they have to compile fast.  And I don't want to spend the time copy/pasting a GCC or MSVC example from https://godbolt.org/ like I did when editing your question.  If you do, go ahead.  Otherwise may there's a good canonical Q&A about JITs often having more missed optimizations than AoT compilers.