# Why does multiple class member assignments produce redundant assembly?

Tags: c#, assembly, x86-64, disassembly

While playing with C# I came across to this "strange behavior".

**The function**

```cs
public static Vec3 f() 
{
    var v = new Vec3();

    v.x = 0;
    v.y = 0;
    v.z = 0;

    v.x = 0;
    v.y = 0;
    v.z = 0;

    v.x = 0;
    v.y = 0;
    v.z = 0;

    return v;
}
```

When you use the `class` keyword for `Vec3` then the **asm** output produces redundant code:

```cs
public class Vec3
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;
}
```

**asm**

```
C.f()
    L0000: sub rsp, 0x28
    L0004: mov rcx, 0x7ff7aaa5d040
    L000e: call 0x00007ff801dba370
    L0013: xor edx, edx
    L0015: mov [rax+8], edx
    L0018: mov [rax+0xc], edx
    L001b: mov [rax+0x10], edx
    L001e: mov [rax+8], edx      ; isn't this redundant?
    L0021: mov [rax+0xc], edx    ; isn't this redundant?
    L0024: mov [rax+0x10], edx   ; isn't this redundant?
    L0027: mov [rax+8], edx      ; isn't this redundant?
    L002a: mov [rax+0xc], edx    ; isn't this redundant?
    L002d: mov [rax+0x10], edx   ; isn't this redundant?
    L0030: add rsp, 0x28
    L0034: ret
```

But whit `struct` keyword we get the following output:

```cs
public struct Vec3
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;
}
```

**asm**

```
C.f()
    L0000: xor eax, eax
    L0002: mov [rcx], eax
    L0004: mov [rcx+4], eax
    L0007: mov [rcx+8], eax
    L000a: mov rax, rcx
    L000d: ret
```

## Question

Are those assembly lines not redundant? If no, can you please explain me why?

#### Note

I know that `class` and `struct` are NOT the same. The question is about multiple `MOV` instructions.

Comment: Where are you seeing this x86 assembly? C# compiles to IL, not x86.

Comment: "*isn't this redundant?*" -- yes, but I remember reading somewhere that the compiler doesn't attempt to detect redundant initialisation like this. It's hard to detect in the general case, slow, and offers maginal benefit in real-world code

Comment: @Dai The JIT then turns IL into x86/x64. https://sharplab.io is a good resource, but you can also use a debugger

Comment: @canton7 is it a general case for classes. Or why can it detect the `struct` ones?

Comment: Presumably there's an optimization pass for something else for structs which happens to catch this case

Comment: **Exactly what** `csc` compiler options did you use?

Comment: @canton7 Ah, ok cool. You can write the answer if you want. Maybe share the link where you got the information. c:

Comment: Not sure if it provides any help or clarity, but structs are both allocated on the stack (except when boxed) and not accessed by reference. This could very well change the rules for a compiler when optimizing code. It's obvious to a human that it's redundant but to a compiler, under these circumstances, it might not be.

Comment: @Dai [See here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSB0AcgK5QCmATgJYDGEA3OunAMy4LYDC2A3utgNxs8ANmwA1MjWAB7CmwBmACgCU2foL5pBO7ADcwFfdgC82AHZkA7hKmz5qxmg279+ABqnsmJ64F78AE0vHxddAIAtEKcwnQDPM1DtPwDgxN8U/Cj0pmTXeOjYwVTCvPCs0qKBOAB2fQyBAF90RqA==)

Comment: @Hrant It was somewhere on the Roslyn issue tracker, months ago, I think

Comment: @AlphaDelta Depends how far down the rabbit hole you want to go. A struct field in a class is very much allocated on the heap (as part of that class), and you can easily take a reference to a struct, and also any instance method on a struct is invoked by passing a reference of that struct to the method (although that isn't visible in C#)

Comment: It's worth noting that the `struct` case here is the jitter's doing: the compiler output [is full of redundant assignments](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYAYAEMEDoByArgLYCmATmAMYDOA3KqjAMzZyYDCmA3qpv9lY4AbJgBqpKsAD25VgDMAFAEpMfAbxQDtmAG4BDcnswBeTADtSAd3GSZclQxTqde3AA1TmdE9f9duACaXj4uOgEAWiFOYdoBnmahWn4BwYm+KbhR6YzJrvHRsQKphXnhWaVF/DAA7HoZ/AC+qI1AA=). It also only happens in Release.

Comment: Code that deals with value types tends to get more optimizations than code that deals with reference types, particularly because value types are normally used in less common scenarios where performance is a premium. Because of their inability to "escape" the method they're in (which is not generally true of reference types) such optimizations are also much easier. In this case, the assignments are obviously redundant, but if there was even a single instance of the class getting passed as a parameter to a method, or stored in a field, they might not be (if threads got involved).

Comment: As discussed in comments on [Is there a reason why Roslyn does not optimize multiple increments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66766573), the current JIT optimizer for MS's implementation of C# doesn't do as good a job as an ahead-of-time compiler would.  That's typical for JITs; they have to compile fast because compile-time is part of per-run performance.